# Is "XML SCRIPT" alive yet?

Tags: asp.net, xml, ajax, scripting

I heard about in ASP.NET AJAX in Action book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Script is the name given to more than one unrelated technologies., ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Script

One is a way to transform XML, like XSLT. That one is dead, but Ajax in Action wasn't talking about that.

The one that you are asking about is a Microsoft technology that puts XML into a script tag with a type of "text/xml-script" that has a family resemblance to WPF.

It got at least as far as the MS-Ajax Futures 3.5 release, Ref: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22457 which is a beta/preview. I imagine it got killed in favor of work on silverlight which isn't just WPF-like syntax in a script tag but really is WPF syntax, and then the failure of MS-Ajax to compete with jquery probably led to MS not pushing forward Ms-Ajax anymore, including xml script. And now it looks like Silverlight isn't being developed any further either.